# Artifactory: create permission via api fails with "HTTP 405 method not allowed"

Tags: artifactory

After reading the official Documentation about [creating permissions](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/permissions)

I've copied the sample data from the site and place it in `test.json` (and fixed the missing `}` at the end in order to have a valid json file.)

Then the following command failed:

`curl -X  POST 'http://localhost:8082/access/api/v2/permissions/Checkmate.json' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer  eyJ2ZXIiOi...' -d @test.json`

leads to:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "message" : "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"
  } ]
}
```

I've tried the [delete permissions example](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/delete-permission) and that worked with the same bearer token.

What am I doing wrong - the documentation is not precise enough.

PS: running artifactory version `7.77.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a file called my-test.json with below content

```
{
   "name": "my-test",
   "resources": {
       "artifact": {
           "actions": {
               "users": {user1},
               "groups": {
                   "mygroup" : [ "ANNOTATE", "WRITE", "READ" ]
               }
           },
           "targets": {
               "mytest": {}
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Then I ran the below command.

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXXX" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -T my-test.json https://myartifactory.jfrog.io/access/api/v2/permission
```

My permission target was created successfully. Please give a try with this command.

Comment: Thanks, that worked and it's far better than the [official documentation](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/permissions).

In case someone want to copy paste your example, you might want to correct the url (due to missing s in permissions): `access/api/v2/permissions`